# Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.21.0:build window 10 home OR pro

Tags: maven, docker, plugins

Integrate Docker with Maven Docker Maven Plugin. I had a problem getting the Docker Run through Maven, on window 10 home machine. Build Failure with the following trace.

```
DOCKER> Cannot create docker access object  [Cannot extract API version from 
server https://192.168.99.100:2376 : 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find 
valid certification path to requested target]
[INFO]
Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.21.0:build (default-
cli) on project fleetman: Cannot create docker access object: Cannot extract 
API version from server https://192.168.99.100:2376 : 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find 
valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Answer (score 5):

**If you are on window 10 home the solution is:**

We are making clean package docker:build as goal

First get the environment variable of your docker installation

```
$ docker-machine env
```

You will get something like this

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="C:\Users\vimal\.docker\machine\machines\default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
export COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS="true"
```

This **DOCKER_CERT_PATH** is already in your machine, you can verify the folder content that has the CA certificates, already generated during installation, nothing to do further.

You have to only add the entries into your POM file, let us see...

```
<!-- DMP Docker Maven Plugin  https://dmp.fabric8.io/ -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.21.0</version>

            <configuration>
                <!-- <dockerHost>http://127.0.0.1:2375</dockerHost> for window 10 pro-->
                <!-- this is for Mac and Amazon Linux -->
                <!-- <dockerHost>unix:///var/run/docker.sock</dockerHost> -->
                <dockerHost>tcp://192.168.99.100:2376</dockerHost>
                <verbose>true</verbose>

                <images>
                    <image>
                        <name>vimalkrishna/abc-app</name>
                        <build>
                            <dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker/</dockerFileDir>

                            <assembly>
                                <descriptorRef>artifact</descriptorRef>
                            </assembly>
                            <tags>
                                <tag>latest</tag>
                            </tags>
                        </build>
                    </image>
                </images>
                <certPath>C:\Users\vimal\.docker\machine\machines\default</certPath>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

You can copy paste above to your POM and change the XXX of your machine. Only below 2 entries are what you get from **env** need to be adjusted.
Dockertoolkit(Window 10 home) needs 192.168.99.100 unlike 127.0.0.1 of pro version of window 10

```
<name>vimalkrishna/abc-app</name>

<dockerHost>tcp://192.168.99.100:2376</dockerHost>
<certPath>C:\Users\XXX\.docker\machine\machines\default</certPath>
```

Thats all, The build will succeed. Put your user and password in local config file

**Important!**
The location of  the Dickerfile in your application is

```
<dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker/</dockerFileDir>
```

Means create a folder **docker** inside src/main/

[image]

Comment: I am getting below after giving certificate path:

Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.39.1:build (default-cli) on project services: Cannot create docker access object: "C:\Users\hp\.minikube\certs\key.pem (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect) -> [Help 1]